# Can a gravitational field be focused like a magnetic field?

Tags: gravity, magnetic-fields

A pyramidal magnet will focus a greater magnetic field at the top of the pyramid than at the bottom.  See [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNtZUFhjquw)   Is there any evidence that the same holds for a gravitational field?  Perhaps the peak of a mountain will have a stronger gravitational field than would normally be the case for flat land.   Or perhaps the whole planet would need to be pyramidal shaped for this to occur.

Answer (score 4):

I used numerical integration to find the gravitational field at the top (i.e., apex point) and bottom (i.e, center of the square base) of an [equilateral square pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramid#Equilateral_square_pyramid,_Johnson_solid_J1). The force at the top is only 64.9% of that at the bottom.

Details:

The gravitational force on a test mass $m$ due to an arbitrary mass distribution with density $\rho(\mathbf r')$ can be calculated by considering the arbitrary mass distribution to be a collection of infinitesimal point masses $dM=\rho\, d^3\mathbf r'$. The infinitesimal force on $m$ at position $\mathbf r$ due to $dM$ at position $\mathbf r'$ is

$$d\mathbf F(\mathbf r)=-Gm\rho(\mathbf r')\,d^3\mathbf r'\frac{\mathbf r-\mathbf r'}{|\mathbf r-\mathbf r'|^3}.$$

(This is just the fancy version of

$$\mathbf F=-\frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat r$$

for when neither mass is at the origin and one of them is infinitesimal.)

The total force is found by doing an integral over the mass distribution to add up the infinite number of infinesimal contributions:

$$\mathbf F(\mathbf r)=-Gm\int_V\rho(\mathbf r')\,d^3\mathbf r'\frac{\mathbf r-\mathbf r'}{|\mathbf r-\mathbf r'|^3}.$$

For an object of uniform density, the $\rho$ is just a constant and comes out of the integral.

An equilateral square pyramid with side length $L$ has height $h=L/\sqrt2$. I took the pyramid to have its base vertices at $(\pm L/2,\pm L/2,0)$ and its apex at $(0,0,L/\sqrt2)$. At distance $z$ above the base, the pyramid extends between $\pm(\frac{L}{2}-\frac{z}{\sqrt2})$ in the $x$ and $y$ directions.

So the integral over the pyramid is

$$\mathbf F(x,y,z)=-Gm\rho\int_0^{L/\sqrt2}dz'\int_{-(\frac{L}{2}-\frac{z'}{\sqrt2})}^{\frac{L}{2}-\frac{z'}{\sqrt2}}dx'\int_{-(\frac{L}{2}-\frac{z'}{\sqrt2})}^{\frac{L}{2}-\frac{z'}{\sqrt2}}dy'\frac{(x-x')\hat x+(y-y')\hat y+(z-z')\hat z}{[(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2]^{3/2}}.$$

Taking $G$, $m$, $\rho$, and $L$ as 1, I used *Mathematica*'s `NIntegrate` function (with the option `method->"LocalAdaptive"`) to numerically integrate this at the top, $(0,0,1/\sqrt2)$ and the bottom $(0,0,0)$.

The results were

$$\mathbf F_\text{top}=(0,0,-0.961204)$$

and

$$\mathbf F_\text{bottom}=(0,0,1.48096).$$

Comment: This is exactly the thing I would like to learn.  Can you post the complete mathematical solution to that here, or perhaps message me with it?

Comment: I've added the details of the calculation.

Comment: I've looked at this very carefully   It appears that the method is to integrate a zillion individual points to find their gravitational field strength at the apex and the base of the pyramid, with the distance 1/r^2 being the key factor in the calculation.  But this method does not consider any synergistic effects of the pyramid shape.  Each point is measured only individually.  So if we used this method for the pyramid magnetic field, we would get essentially the same result .   Please correct me if I have misinterpreted your answer.

Comment: @foolishmuse There are no synergistic effects. Newtonian gravitational fields are simply additive. The field of $N$ masses is the vector sum of the fields of each individual mass.

Comment: @foolishmuse With magnetic fields the orientation of the individual magnetic dipoles matters. There is no corresponding “direction of mass” for gravity. I have not tried doing the magnetic calculation. I listened to the first few seconds of the video and would not believe anything that fellow told me, although he may well be right.

Comment: @foolishmuse The calculation I’ve done here is the same kind of calculation that tells you that the gravitational acceleration at the surface of the Earth is 9.8 meters per second per second. Each atom in the Earth is pulling on you, in different directions with different strengths depending in how far away they are. Their non-synergistic additive effect is the same as if the mass if the Earth were concentrated in a point at its center, even though of course  it is not.

Comment: I'm sure you are correct, it's just that using that method would give no focusing for a pyramid magnet.  It's interesting to look at the gravitational field on earth https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth and see the spikes in the Andes.  I think the answer below about monopole versus dipole is probably the full answer, but even that doesn't provide an explanation.  I'm working to get a better understanding of fields in general. Your math answer was extremely helpful in providing a real world example of the formulas.  And I had never heard of Mathematica before.

Comment: @foolishmuse I think this method *would* probably lead to a more intense magnetic field at the small end of the pyramid when the *direction of the dipole moments* are taken into account. They are presumably angled a bit toward the central axis rather than parallel.

Answer (score 4):

Magnetic fields are fundamentally different to gravitational fields, even in the non-relativistic case, because there are no magnetic monopoles. By contrast, every piece of mass looks like a monopole.

**The Maths**

Using standard Newtonian gravity, the gravitational potential $U(\vec{x})$ of a mass distribution $\mu(\vec{y})$ is expressible via the Green's function for Poisson's equation:

$$V(x) = \int d^3 y \frac{-G \mu(y)}{|x-y|}$$

giving a gravitational field $\vec{g}(\vec{x}) = -\nabla V(\vec{x})$. Note that for the simple case of $\mu(y) = \delta^3(y-y_0)$, you recover the Newtonian gravity formula. Note that there is no antimass, $\mu \ge 0$.

This essentially says that the field from any mass distribution just looks like a point mass that's been 'smeared,' i.e. not *that* different to a sphere.

For a uniform density cone of mass M (nicer to parameterise than a square pyramid), the vector potential at a point in cylindrical coordinates $\rho, \phi, z$ is given by

$$\frac{-3MG}{\pi R^2 h}\int_0^R d\rho' \int_0^hdz' \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi' \left( (z-z')^2 + \rho^2 + \rho'^2 - 2\rho\rho' \cos(\phi')\right)^{-1/2}$$

This is not particularly illuminating, so it's more physically insightful to look into an approximation scheme.

**Multipole Moments**

You may wish to learn about the [multipole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion) - a systematic way of expanding distributions of charge or mass, writing them as a sum of a monopole, a dipole, a quadrupole and higher moments. The potential from a monopole decays as $1/r$, from a dipole as $1/r^2$, from a quadrupole as $1/r^3$ and so on.

The monopole moment decays more slowly than all higher moments, so if it's nonzero it will eventually dominate when far away from the distribution. Since there's no such thing as anti-mass, monopole moments of mass distributions always win. However, the monopole moment of an arrangement of magnetic dipoles is always exactly zero.

**Polarisability**

The most critical difference between the magnetic pyramid and the mass pyramid is the fact that one is *polarisable*. Magnetic media are filled with spins that react when an external field is applied. In the special case of ferromagnets, nearest-neighbour spin-spin interactions collaborate to align with the applied field, strengthening it by a factor of 100 or more. The geometry and connectivity of the material will actually affect how the spins communicate, and hence the bulk polarisation. By contrast, mass just sits there being a weight - there is no material that acts as a field amplifier in the same way.

Comment: So because a planet is a gravitational monopole, it can't have the same focused gravitational field as a magnetic dipole.  What goes in one end must come out the other.   I was looking at a map of the Earth's gravitational field https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth and it seems there is increased gravity along the Andes mountains in South America.  But I wouldn't want to say that it was caused by this effect.

Comment: Not exactly - see the edited answer. The modulation on that map is *very, very* small - usually under 1% of the field strength. Mountains have stronger gravitational field because they're big and heavy, not because they're pointy.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is 'Yes'.  There is an exact analogy between classical magnetostatics and Newtonian gravity.

For example, the magnetic field at the pointed top of a uniformally axially-magnetized pyramid or cone approaches infinity. The field can be viewed as arising from a shell of magnetic poles (charge) where the magnetization terminates on the surface of the cone.  Likewise the gravitational field at the point of a conical hollow shell of mass can also approach infinity.

In magnetism, there are inevitably some balancing negative poles somewhere, but that is irrelevant since they can be moved arbitrarily far away with a suitable magnet design (e.g. a semi-infinite magnetized needle)

There are some 'details' of course.  *Infinite* magnetic fields cannot be achieved in practice because there are no magnetic materials capable of sustaining infinite fields without demagnetizing and so the magnetic poles cannot be confined to an infinitesimally thin shell at the surface. Likewise matter cannot be confined to an infinitesimally thin shell and still retain any mass.

A calculation of the gravitational field at the pointed top of a *hollow* pyramid of osmium (or, better still, *neutron star stuff*) will show an inordinately large gravitational field.

Comment: I know I've asked a good question when I get diametrically opposed answers.   Can you point me to a reference on this?

Comment: i believe he is referring to possion's equation and it's analogue in electrodynamics http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/reh10/lectures/nst-mmii-chapter2.pdf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_vector_potential https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EW08rD-GFh0&ab_channel=KhanAcademy

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch to call the analogy "exact" - the fact that they both obey the Poisson equation does not erase the key fundamental differences between the fields. There is no negative mass, and there are no magnetic monopoles.

Comment: @ExpertNonexpert  I've looked through all three of your references carefully, but I can't find what I'm looking for in regards to the original question.  Perhaps you can point me a little closer.

Comment: @foolishmuse Does this help?  It's talking about electric rather then magnetic poles but the same applies.https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226577/why-is-the-force-on-the-charge-at-the-tip-of-a-cone-infinite

Comment: Thanks for that.  The example stays with the same problem of an electrical system being a dipole, while a gravitational mass is a monopole, as mentioned in @catalogue_number's answer above.  But when I look elsewhere, I see that a mass can be considered a dipole based on the distance from the centre of the mass. Is this correct?  How can I reconcile between your answer and his answer?  BTW I found your paper on GLEW very interesting.  Quite innovative but very different from my own theory of quantum gravity.

Comment: @foolishmuse  mmmh...  what is GLEW?

Comment: @catalogue_number I can stretch the analogy even further :-) https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/591103/is-the-force-due-to-gravity-between-two-objects-immersed-in-a-fluid-correctly-gi  A helium balloon and a CO2 balloon side-by-side in a room full of air will create a dipole gravitational field